# Disable Radio button if default value is "inactive"

Tags: 7, entities

I need to **disable** other radio button(s) when **[#default_value] => Inactive** as in below code it is?
I tried with different ways but unsuccessful. Kindly let me know how to do that?

**PHP CODE**

```
foreach($form['field_complaint_status'] as $key=>$val)
{
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($val['field_complaint_status']); exit;
}
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [#type] => container
    [#attributes] => Array
        (
            [class] => Array
                (
                    [0] => field-type-list-text
                    [1] => field-name-field-complaint-status
                    [2] => field-widget-options-buttons
                )

        )

    [#weight] => 13
    [#tree] => 1
    [#language] => und
    [und] => Array
        (
            [#entity] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [vid] => 544
                    [uid] => 754
                    [title] => Complaint/Feedback
                    [log] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [comment] => 1
                    [promote] => 1
                    [sticky] => 0
                    [nid] => 544
                    [type] => complaint_or_feedback
                    [language] => en
                    [created] => 1492408487
                    [changed] => 1492587955
                    [tnid] => 0
                    [translate] => 0
                    [revision_timestamp] => 1492587955
                    [revision_uid] => 754
                    [field_type] => Array
                        (
                            [und] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [value] => Complaint
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [field_complaint_status] => Array
                        (
                            [und] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [value] => Inactive
                                        )

                                )

                        )
                    [cid] => 0
                    [last_comment_timestamp] => 1492408487
                    [last_comment_name] => 
                    [last_comment_uid] => 754
                    [comment_count] => 0
                    [menu_node_links] => Array
                        (
                        )
                    [picture] => 0
                )

            [#entity_type] => node
            [#bundle] => complaint_or_feedback
            [#field_name] => field_complaint_status
            [#language] => und
            [#field_parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => field_complaint_status
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [#columns] => Array
                (
                    [0] => value
                )

            [#title] => 
            [#description] => 
            [#required] => 1
            [#delta] => 0
            [#type] => radios
            [#default_value] => Inactive
            [#options] => Array
                (
                    [Active] => active
                    [Inactive] => inactive
                )

            [#value_key] => value
            [#element_validate] => Array
                (
                    [0] => options_field_widget_validate
                )

            [#properties] => Array
                (
                    [filter_xss] => 1
                    [strip_tags] => 
                    [strip_tags_and_unescape] => 
                    [empty_option] => 
                    [optgroups] => 
                )

            [#after_build] => Array
                (
                    [0] => field_form_element_after_build
                )

        )

    [#access] => 1
)
```

Comment: Where is you radio button code?

Comment: I created it using manage field of a content type. I didn't code it.

Comment: what is the field name??

Comment: its name is field_complaint_status as I already mention in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done with JS, See code below

```
jQuery(".inactive input").each(function(index, element) {
    jQuery(this).attr("disabled",true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the #states property to achieve that. The #states property can be applied to all Form API elements.

```
  $form['student_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => array(
      'high_school' => t('High School'),
      'undergraduate' => t('Undergraduate'),
      'graduate' => t('Graduate'),
    ),
    '#title' => t('What type of student are you?'),
  );
  $form['high_school'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('High School Information'),
    // This #states rule says that the "high school" fieldset should only
    // be shown if the "student_type" form element is set to "High School".
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="student_type"]' => array('value' => 'high_school'),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

References : 
[states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753010/drupal-form-api-dynamically-hide-or-show-fields-based-on-input)

[form_example_states_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example_states.inc/function/form_example_states_form/7.x-1.x)

Comment: Please re-read my question I asked about **disable** other values (radio buttons) of the same field as above mentioned **[#default_value]**. **[#default_value]** means the same field. Your answer is referring to show/hide fields as [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) works.

Comment: Can you provide  image of the form?

Comment: I have figured out. See my answer below